# how to redirect to j_security_check in the managed bean?

Tags: icefaces, jaas, j-security-check

i've successfully run a based FORM authentication project and trying to do the same with an icefaces project. In other terms i want to use ice:form instead of form, so i was wondering if i could  redirect the login request to j_security_check in the managed bean:

```
public void myMethod(ActionEvent e){
  //some code that redirects to j_security_check
}
```

and in my login page:

```
<ice:commandButton value="login" ActionListener="#{myBean.myMethod}"/>
```

But i don't really know how to do it, and i don't really find documentation about j_security_check and how it really works.

Comment: Please fix your post, you appear to be missing some text in this line: "In other terms i want to use instead of , so i was wondering...."

Answer (score 0):

You can have a form with `action="j_security_check"`, with text fields or hidden fields containing the username and password. You can bind these fields to variables in your managed bean. You can use a submit button in the form instead of `<ice:commandButton>`.

If you have to use the `<ice:commandButton>`, you can use Javascript to send a "myform.submit()" script:

```
public void myMethod(ActionEvent e)
{
      //Some other code...

      JavascriptContext.addJavascriptCall(
            FacesContext.getCurrentInstance(), "document,forms.myForm.submit()");    
}
```

You can also dynamically create a form element in Javascript, assign username/password values and submit it, using the `JavascriptContext.addJavascriptCall()` method

Comment: the messing text is the most important, sorry i didn't pay attention. The problem is that i want to use only icefaces components and it doesn't seem to be working this why i'm trying to use the managedbean.

Comment: Well you try can a hack. Give your `<ice:form>` and ID using the `id="iceformID"` attribute. You can use this javascript code behind your button: `document.getElementById('iceformID').submit();` You can use this on the onclick event, since the <ice:commandButton> has this event. Or if you really want to use the Managed Bean, send this code through the actionListener as described above.